# Convert Word Mail Merge documents from 2003 to 2010 format

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge

I need to convert about 100 mail merge documents from 2003 to 2010 format(.doc to .docx).

The trouble I am having is that in order to convert the documents I need to open them. But some of them won't open because I don't have the correct header files/ any data in the files.

Is there a way I can convert these documents to the new format without opening them?

Note: The converter provided by microsoft fails. Also it doesn't matter how. If there's a program or code that can accomplish this then it is helpful.

Comment: **The trouble I am having is that in order to convert the documents I need to open them. But some of them won't open because I don't have the correct header files/ any data in the files.** This seems like it would be a problem.  Why do you need to convert files that do not have any data in them?

Comment: These template files are used by another program which fills a temp file with data(amanda.txt) and uses that data to populate the template. Basically I dont want to have to go generate a document then change the template for each one(since the data can be different). Found this out after I asked the question and it looks like the only solution at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [npoi](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) project.

Hope this helps.